# ¿Como iniciar desde la segunda propiedad de un objeto en javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

tengo el siguiente metodo:

```
 $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: '../ws/parqueos'
   }).then(function (success){
            $scope.parqueos = success.data.records;        
            for($scope.parqueosDisponibles in  $scope.parqueos)
            {
             console.log($scope.parqueos[$scope.parqueosDisponibles]);
            }

   },function (error){

   });
```

la variable `$scope.parqueos = success.data.records;`

almacena lo que viene en el siguiente JSON, exactamente en la propiedad `"records":`

```
{
  "message": "Consulta Exitosa: Parqueos",
  "result": true,
  "records": {
    "id_info": 2,
    "estac1": 1,
    "estac2": 1,
    "estac3": 1,
    "estac4": 1,
    "estac5": 0,
    "estac6": 0,
    "estac7": 0,
    "estac8": 0,
    "estac9": 1
  }
}
```

resulta que debo realizar un contador de las propiedades estac1, estac2,estac3, estac4, estac5, estac6, estac7, estac8, estac9 cuando estos tengan valor 1 debo ir sumando con el fin de obtener un total de parqueos diponibles, pero no debo tomar en cuenta la propiedad del objeto records,  `"id_info": 2,`

para ellos ando utilizando esta estructura:

```
for($scope.parqueosDisponibles in  $scope.parqueos)
{
  console.log($scope.parqueos[$scope.parqueosDisponibles]);
}
```

pero recorre todos los valores del objeto.  ¿Como puedo iniciar desde la segunda propiedad del objeto `records`?
o ¿alguna otra solucion para mi problema?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes simplemente basarte en el **indice=1**

```js
var x = {
  "id_info": 2,
  "estac1": 1,
  "estac2": 1,
  "estac3": 1,
  "estac4": 1,
  "estac5": 0,
  "estac6": 0,
  "estac7": 0,
  "estac8": 0,
  "estac9": 1
};

var arrayX = Object.values(x);
var suma = 0;
for (var i = 1; i < arrayX.length; i++) {
  if (arrayX[i]) {
    suma++;
  }
}
console.log("SUMA DESDE EL SEGUNDO ELEMENTO", suma);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple vista podrías hacer lo siguiente:

Definir una variable de 'control', ejemplo:

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '../ws/parqueos'
}).then(function (success){
    //Definimos la variable de 'control'
    var control = false;
    $scope.parqueos = success.data.records;        

        for($scope.parqueosDisponibles in  $scope.parqueos){
            if(control == true){
                console.log($scope.parqueos[$scope.parqueosDisponibles]);
            }
            else{
                control = true;
            }
        }

    },function (error){

});
```

Espero y te funcione.